# Error: Attempted to handle event `didSetProperty` when Deleting record model ember

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, jsbin

I have an issue when i deleteRecord in my app and i know the reason why this is happening but i can not figure the issue out

I have reproduced the case [here](http://jsbin.com/piboxi/1/edit),

I add an Invoice and then i add  more transactions.

The problem happens after i have removed the invoice, this is the error message

**Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Attempted to handle event `didSetProperty` on  while in state root.deleted.saved. Called with {name: transactionsAmounts, oldValue: NaN, originalValue: undefined, value: 0}.**

Basically there is an error model {transactionsAmount} on removing the Invoice

The transactionAmounts is the sum of any single of transaction and is created here in the models

```
  transactionsAmounts: DS.attr('string'),
  setTransactionAmount : function(){
    if(this.get("transactions.length")>0){
      this.get("transactions").then(function(transactions){
        var sum=0;
        transactions.forEach(function(transaction){
           sum+=transaction.get("total");
        });
        this.set("transactionsAmounts",sum);
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }.observes('transactions.length', 'transactions.@each.total'),
```

At the moment of removing the invoice the transactionAmount is not deleted, how i can make this happening in order to remove the Invoice mode (which hasMany transaction) and not get the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update:

This should be fixed in **Ember Data beta 16**.

---

### Original answer:

Because of bug introduced in Ember Data beta 14 deleted models are still present in collections, so you have to make sure objects you are using aren't deleted. This code fixed it for me:

Invoice model:

```
App.Invoice = DS.Model.extend({
  title         : DS.attr('string'),
  transactions  : DS.hasMany('transaction', { async:true}),
  transactionsAmounts: DS.attr('string'),
  setTransactionAmount : function(){
    if(!this.get('isDeleted') && this.get("transactions.length") > 0){
      this.get("transactions").then(function(transactions){
        var sum=0;
        transactions.forEach(function(transaction){
          if(!transaction.get('isDeleted'))
          {
            sum += transaction.get("total");
          }
        });
        if(!this.get('isDeleted'))
        {
          this.set("transactionsAmounts",sum);
        }
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }.observes('transactions.length', 'transactions.@each.total'),
});
```

Remove action in controller:

```
remove: function() {
      var transactions = this.get('model.transactions'),
          list = transactions.toArray();
      list.forEach(function(transaction) {
        if (!transaction.get('isDeleted'))
        {
          transaction.deleteRecord();
          transactions.removeObject();
        }
      });
      var model = this.get('model');
      if(!model.get('isDeleted'))
      {
        this.get('model').deleteRecord();
      }
      // and then go to the fatturas route
      this.transitionToRoute('fatturas');
      // set deleteMode back to false
      this.set('deleteMode', false);
    },
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsbin.com/mosegusohi/3/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: I was not aware of the isDeleted status, very new to ember, great explanation, code and jsBin working example

Comment: You might also want to use `destroyRecord()` instead of  `deleteRecord()` so it will be persisted to the server API(if any). And this is issue on GitHub for bug I mentioned in answer: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2666

Comment: i read in the comments that this a workaround by filtering items by ('isDeleted') to avoid the bug, in my project i am using ember-data 1.0.0-beta.10 and it was the same problem , your code also has fixed it in my app with that data version